# can php script update my sql when called from ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, json

I have a script that makes an ajax request to a php script

```
    // ajax request for Weather       
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Json/weatherAPI.php" ,
          data: { 
          postcode: postcode,
          display:'fadeout' ,
          color:'blue' ,
          timed_display:'20'},
          dataType: 'json',   
          success:JsonDataReturned ,

    });
```

This calls my PHP script which then queires a weather API and returns Json data back to my script above, **ALL this works fine (below)**

```
         $postcode = $_POST['postcode'];
         $url = "http://www.myweather2.com/developer/forecast.ashx?uac=" . $api . "&output=json&query=" . $postcode ; 
         $response = fopen($url, "r");
         $response = fgets($response, 4096);
         echo $response ;
```

After this, In the same PHP script I want to update my SQL DB with the 'post' data, see below ( The database is connected)

```
      $query = 'UPDATE data_weather_control SET ';
      $values = array();

      foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {

                  $query .= ' '.$key.' = :'.$key.',';   // the :$name part is the placeholder, e.g. :zip
                  $values[':'.$key] = $value;           // save the placeholder

      };

      $query = substr($query, 0, -1) ; // remove last , 
      $query .= " WHERE id='dataman' " ;

      $qry = $pdo->prepare($query);
      $qry->execute($values);            // bind placeholder array to the query and execute everything
```

I believe all looks ok and I know I have the 'post' data but it will not update my database, however If I run the php script alone (without the ajax call) it does update. My question : are my PDO statements correct or does the PHP script not perform properly when calles as an ajax request ?

Any help please ??,

Comment: Can you move you this line echo $response ; in the last and try

Comment: Ten seconds is all that is required to zap your database. SQL injection eh?

Comment: Moving the echo does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't know whether the request is AJAX unless you set a variable and check it yourself, so the request should work. I suspect that PHP is looking for 'POST' variables but your ajax may be sending a JSON string that will have to be decoded. Do a print_r($_POST) and see the difference between running it "alone" or from your ajax call. You might need to parse incoming JSON (in the body of the request). Whatever it is, that print_r will help you see the problem.

Comment: I have check the post data and it does all seem correct in the statement

Comment: How do you run the php script alone?

Comment: I make some post data in the php script   $_POST['top'] = "9999" ; etc